# Does Pagination with Infinite load affect SEO

Tags: seo

I have a website developed in React for the frontend. I can see links on the pages with **NO** infinite load have got indexed on Google. However, links on the ones which have infinite loading for pagination haven't got indexed yet. It's been 3 weeks. Do I have to convert the pages to normal pagination without infinite loading?

Answer (score 2):

Since your front-end is in react.js and google has limitations for parsing(crawling) content within javascript, it would be a bit troublesome for you.

Don't worry. Where there is a problem, there are solutions.

Although there are multiple ways to solve this problem, there is one in particular recommended by google:
"To make sure that search engines can crawl individual items linked from an infinite scroll page, make sure that you or your content management system produces a paginated series (component pages) to go along with your infinite scroll."

Comment: For details, refer: https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/02/infinite-scroll-search-friendly.html

Comment: https://www.quicksprout.com/how-to-create-an-seo-friendly-infinite-scrolling-page/

Comment: Try it out and let me know if the problem still persists after a few weeks. Google might take some time to crawl the page and index them, after you have made changes.

Answer (score 1):

Googlebot doesn't scroll.  Googlebot doesn't click on anything.  The only thing that Googlebot does to discover content is scan the document and look for links.  It can find them in `<a href` as well as strings that look like they could be links in JavaScript.  If the only way to get to the content is to scroll to it, Google will never find it.

You can usually overcome this by creating links to page 2+ while still allowing users to scroll to get there.